# How to determine the overall range of several variables of a data.frame, using variable indices?

Tags: arrays, r, list, indexing, dataframe

I have a data.frame that looks similar to:

```
data <- data.frame(
  x=c(1:10)
  , y1=c(3,5,1,8,2,4,5,0,8,2)
  , y2=c(1,8,2,1,4,5,3,0,8,2)
  , y3=c(13,88,2,1,4,5,3,0,-8,1)
)
```

(Actually there are much more variabes in the data.frame and the variables have longer names.)

I'd like to determine the range of

1. the variable x
2. of all the other variables

one way could be:

```
xRange = range(data$x)

# using variable names:
yRange = range(data$y1, data$y2, data$y3)

# using variable indices
yRange = range(data[[2]], data[[3]], data[[4]])
```

I also tried to use ranges, so that I dont habe to add every single variable name or index:

```
yRange = range(data[[c(2:4)]])
yRange = range(data[[2:4]])
```

Is there a way to get a list of all values from sveral variables of a data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you try to do. But why not to use `subset` to remove some variable by name and get range of the result?

```
range(subset(data,select=-x))
-8 88
```

Or equivalent to this by using variable indexes ( not recommended)

```
range(subset(data,select=2:4))
```